# What is Sysrq+J "Thaw frozen filesystems" and why it fails?

Tags: linux, filesystems, sysrq

Is it expected to unfreeze processes that are in uninterruptible sleep because of filesystem issue (NFS, FUSE, bug)?

If I press Sysrq+J on my Linux, it halts the system and prints "Emergency Thaw on sda" in a loop endlessly, not allowing any other SysRqs? Only hard reboot helps then.

Comment: Probably it's a kernel bug, because I've the same problem here, after SysRq+J it started to report the same error in kern.log: "kernel: [160192.060834] Emergency Thaw on sda4" endless around 80000 times per second! After 47,5mln of records and 4,5GB of log within 12 minutes, my machine just DIED!

Comment: Is there already a bug submitted or I should file one?

Comment: I found only this: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12781, but I've just created a new one here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47741

Comment: Also found these: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/984273 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/984265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in kernel: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47741

Comment: Still unpatched apparently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in kernel and it is still present on kernel 3.13 amd64 (from Ubuntu Trusty).

As [_Vi](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47741#c2) tested in his VM using `VBoxManage controlvm <vm_name> keyboardputscancode 1d 38 54  24 a4  d4 b8 9d` with the following results:

```
3.3.6-pf-vi+  : Reproducible
3.2.0-zen-vi+ : Reproducible
3.0.4-zen-vi+ : Reproducible
2.6.37.5-zen-... : Reproducible
2.6.33-zen2-... : Reproducible
2.6.32-zen1-... : Reproducible
2.6.31-zen11-... : Not reproducible
2.6.30-zen2-... : Not reproducible
```

From Dave Chinner we can read:

> The thawing of a filesystem through sysrq-j loops infinitely as it
>   incorrectly detects a thawed filesytsem as frozen and tries to
>   unfreeze repeatedly. This is a regression caused by
>   4504230a71566785a05d3e6b53fa1ee071b864eb ("freeze_bdev: grab active
>   reference to frozen superblocks") in that it no longer returned
>   -EINVAL for superblocks that were not frozen.
>
> Deeper problems arose on further inspection - filesystems frozen with
>   freeze_super() could not be unfrozen by thaw_bdev() so emergency
>   thawing didn't work on anything manually frozen, and deadlocks on
>   sb->s_umount occur as superblocks are iterated in the emergency thaw
>   with it already held for read.
>
> Everywhere we freeze or thaw, we already have a superblock or can get
>   one easily so could call freeze_super() directly. Hence we can kill
>   the bdev level operations and move all the nesting infrastructure up
>   into the superblock level so we have a single consistent interface.

Source: [Re: 2.6.34 echo j > /proc/sysrq-trigger causes inifniteunfreeze/Thaw event](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1006.1/00139.html) at linux-kernel mailing list archive